# Why didn't 'trans-dimensional beings' demolish Enterprise near 1st sphere Enterprise encountered?

Tags: star-trek, tv, star-trek-enterprise

While following ion-trail of pirates, Enterprise encountered the sphere after crossing the cloaking barrier of sphere. Archer ordered to put Enterprise in orbit of sphere to find what pirates were doing there for 8 hours.

The main plan of trans-dimensional beings (sphere builders) was to eliminate humans. And, when Enterprise was put into orbit of 1st sphere, they got the chance.
As Enterprise was in Delphic Expanse at that time, it was easy for them to suspect that humans might screw their plans up. So, it was logical action for them to demolish Enterprise.

As Enterprise was very close to sphere, there wouldn't be any chance for them to survive if huge disturbance were produced (like that time near sphere 41).

Answer (score 3):

- The Sphere Builders were using the Spheres to reconfigure space to be habitable to their people, as a beachhead for an [invasion](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Delphic_Expanse_sphere).
- The Sphere 1 was nearly [1000 years old](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Anomaly_%28episode%29) when they found it.
- No one in the Delphic Expanse knew the purpose of the Spheres.
- The Sphere Builders were called [the Guardians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sphere_Builder) by the Xindi.

Given all this, it would be *very* suspicious if a Sphere suddenly started emitting more energy at the same time a huge number of anomalies appear and destroy the one ship from the species the Sphere Builders told the Xindi to attack.

So, the Sphere Builders were content to wait a few more years while the Xindi dealt with their problem for them.  They only took direct action after the Enterprise made contact and explained the purpose the Spheres' existence.

Additionally, [Sphere 1 was damaged](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Delphic_Expanse_sphere).  It was outputting a lot less power than any of the others, and was easy to gain access to.  I don't believe the Sphere Builders ever even knew the Enterprise or the pirates visited that one until later.

Comment: How could it be suspicious when Xindi didn't have clue that Spheres were build by the Guardians? Xindi-Insectoids suspected this in the last because Archer's words were in their mind.

Comment: Another thing: Anomalies had already destroyed many ships in the Expanse. Xindi would have just laugh at fate of this 1st Earth vessel facing it. It was logical to think that Earth vessel wasn't prepared for that.

Comment: @SachinShekhar I'm not referring to just anomalies destroying the Enterprise, but a sudden increase of anomalies correlated with a far greater energy output - something that had not happened before.  So if such a thing has only ever happened to the Earth ship, what was so different about it?  Answer:  The Guardians wanted it destroyed.  Conclusion:  The Guardians have something to do with the Spheres and the anomalies.

Comment: In eyes of Xindi, Guardians didn't want Human destruction.. They only informed about Xindi future with a suggestion to prevent it.

Comment: Plus, nobody knew about spheres correctly.. Xindi didn't care about sudden increase of anomalies. It'd be assumed as another mystery of sphere!

Comment: And, Xindi were unable to keep eye everywhere in expanse. Mind it, their sensor would never be able to penetrate cloaking barrier of Spheres..